# Using SED to fix internal links in HTML documents?

Tags: bash, sed, grep

### tl;dr:

After four hours of trying, I'm no closer than I was when I started.

I'm trying to add `.html` to the ends of all links (that haven't got another extension) in a lot of html documents. See *Two example links...* below for an example of what I'm aiming to do.

### Main post:

I have a large collection of HTML files, and I'm trying to 'fix' the links, to make them internal links, so that it all works nicely offline. (I'm doing this so that my sister can use the site offline while studying for an exam). The site is no longer online.

I've managed to do some of them (using a simple `SED` command), but I'm completely stuck with most.

#### The two main changes I have to make are:

1. Adding **.html** to the end of all links *that don't already have an extention* (some already have .html, and some have .js, .mp4 or some other extention which doesn't need changing)
2. Changing **https://** to **../../../** (or more for files deeper in the directory tree)

The second step will be easy (I'll use find with *maxdepth mindepth* to determine how deep the file is in the directory tree, and then something like `sed 's/https:\\/../../..//g'` ), however I want to do this bit second because I'm guessing the https will make it easier to find the links that need `.html` adding to the end of them).

Most links are in href tags, but not all of them.

I'm thinking I'll have to use some sort of SED regex, and because different links have to be dealt with differently, probably multiple runs of SED. But SED is not really my specialty.

#### Two example links...

- This link:

`pagespeed.addInstrumentationInit('/mod_pagespeed_beacon', 'beforeunload', '', 'https://www.example.com/learners/levels/2/lessons/13/stories/1','IF77dLwFOP',true,false,'ikd272iAGio');`

needs to be changed to:

`pagespeed.addInstrumentationInit('/mod_pagespeed_beacon', 'beforeunload', '', ../../../www.example.com/learners/levels/2/lessons/13/stories/1.html','IF77dLwFOP',true,false,'ikd272iAGio');`

- And this:

`<a href="https://www.example.com/learners">Home</a>              <ul>`

would have to be:

`<a href="../../../www.example.com/learners.html">Home</a>              <ul>`

#### Where I've gotten so far

As mentioned above, I know how I'm going to do step two, but after four hours of trying I haven't gotten very far with the first step. `grep -Poh 'https://www.example[^"]*'` prints a list of the URLs, but I can't see how that'd be useful. I just can't work out how to get `SED` to place the `.html` in the right places.

Any hints will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GNU awk solution:

```
awk '{while(match($0, /["\x27]https?:\/\/([^\x27"]*)/, a))$0=substr($0,0,RSTART) "../../../" a[1] (a[1]~"\\.[[:alnum:]]{1,5}$"? "" : ".html") substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}1'
```

Put into separated lines:

```
awk '{
    while(match($0, /["\x27]https?:\/\/([^\x27"]*)/, a))  # while there are still url to replace
        $0=substr($0,0,RSTART) "../../../" a[1] (a[1]~"\\.[[:alnum:]]{1,5}$"? "" : ".html") substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) }
    1' file  # 1 for print $0
```

For example:

```
$ cat file
pagespeed.addInstrumentationInit('/mod_pagespeed_beacon', 'beforeunload', '', 'https://www.example.com/learners/levels/2/lessons/13/stories/1','IF77dLwFOP',true,false,'ikd272iAGio');
<a href="https://www.example.com/learners">Home</a>              <ul>
<a href="http://www2.example.com/learner2.html">Home</a>              <ul>
<a href="http://www3.example.com/learner3.html">Home</a><br><br><a href="https://www4.example.com/xhtml">Home</a>
whaeverwhatever

$ awk '{while(match($0, /["\x27]https?:\/\/([^\x27"]*)/, a))$0=substr($0,0,RSTART) "../../../" a[1] (a[1]~"\\.[[:alnum:]]{1,5}$"? "" : ".html") substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}1' file
pagespeed.addInstrumentationInit('/mod_pagespeed_beacon', 'beforeunload', '', '../../../www.example.com/learners/levels/2/lessons/13/stories/1.html','IF77dLwFOP',true,false,'ikd272iAGio');
<a href="../../../www.example.com/learners.html">Home</a>              <ul>
<a href="../../../www2.example.com/learner2.html">Home</a>              <ul>
<a href="../../../www3.example.com/learner3.html">Home</a><br><br><a href="../../../www4.example.com/xhtml.html">Home</a>
whaeverwhatever
```

Comment: You can put newlines inside a single quoted string. That would greatly improve the readability of your awk oneliners

Comment: @glennjackman  Updated.  I'm not keen on this kind of separate though.

Comment: That's amazing. Thank you @Tiw! One thing which I hadn't thought about was that links to https://www.example.com/ ended up as ../../../www.example.com/.html, so I changed those to ../../../www.example.com/index.html using sed. I really need to brush up on awk and sed. Thanks again.